# How to reset the form fields after moving to other tab or on closing the current tab,java and jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I am using jquery-ui tabs ...Actually i want to reset the form fields after closing the current tab or if we move to another tab means form fields should be reseted.. I don't know how to reset the form fields at the close of tab.

Anything help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while closing tab call the below method as like onclick=resetForm('formid')

```
function resetForm(formId){
  $(’#’+formId)[0].reset();
}
```